# Why does the set command not affect the commands immediately followed with & / &&?

Tags: windows-8.1, cmd.exe

I have a bunch of commands using a system variable and they are one lined commands like so:

`set test="blah" && echo %test%`

However, I noticed that the set command's variable is not "set" for the commands on the same line.  If I re-run the second command, it will be able to read the updated variable.  I can use either & or && and the effects are the same.  This behavior occurs with both batch files and simply putting it in the command prompt.

How do I get the `set` command to affect the statements following `&` or `&&`?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the entire command line is evaluated at once, thus the variable `test` is resolved before you run the `set` command.

An easy fix could be to put the commands on separate lines in a batch files and run that.